# With Backendless using android API, trying to retrieve chat history data into chat box with Where clause but no data displaying

Tags: java, android, backendless

here is my RetrieveChatHistory function for retrieving data, nothing is showing in chat box!! help will be appreciated

```
private void RetrieveChatHistory()
{
    String whereClause = "recieverEmail == '".concat(email).concat( "'" );

    BackendlessDataQuery backendlessDataQuery = new BackendlessDataQuery();
    backendlessDataQuery.setWhereClause( whereClause );

    Backendless.Persistence.of(Conversation.class).find(backendlessDataQuery, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Conversation>>() {
       @Override
       public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Conversation> conversationBackendlessCollection) {
           Conversation chatfeeds;

           for (Conversation totalchat : conversationBackendlessCollection.getData()) {
               chatfeeds = new Conversation();
               chatfeeds.setMsg(totalchat.getMsg());
               chatfeeds.setMsgDate(totalchat.getMsgDate());

               convList.add(chatfeeds);
           }
           adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }

       @Override
       public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {

       }
   });
}
```

Comment: So is a fault returned?

Comment: backendlessDataQuery.setWhereClause( whereClause );                              i try to Log.i after that line, but code didn't run after that line and no Log.i run

Comment: so you're running this in debug so you can add breakpoints? and there are no exceptions? Try with `"recieverEmail='".concat(email).concat( "'" )`